# An expression for "Lying on your stomach, kicking your legs and feet up in the air"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

What is a concise way to describe the following action?

> Someone lying on their stomach, kicking their legs and feet up into the air behind them, looking sexy.

The description should be pretty self-explanatory; just need a brief way to say it, preferably in as few words as possible.

Comment: I know of no general term for it, but foot fetishists call it "the pose," as evinced by a Google image search of that phrase.

Comment: In yoga, [locust](https://yoga.com/pose/locust-pose).

Answer (score 13):

Lying on your stomach, facing down is called the **prone** position. Instead, **supine** is lying straight on your back.

[image]

The image above shows a woman performing a **prone leg lift**

[image]

If the leg is not bent at the knee, it is called **prone straight leg raise** / **lift**

[image]
When both legs are raised simultaneously it's called **frog leg lifts**
[Source](http://www.thecoveteur.com/2015/02/19/instant-butt-lift-exercises/)

[image]
And finally, if the person is kicking their legs, it is called **prone flutter kicks**

[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6t0-rCmBQo)

Comment: Don't forget [planking](https://www.google.com/search?q=planking+meme&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis1JHkrLPOAhVEKCYKHdlHDTMQ_AUICCgB&biw=982&bih=1654#tbm=isch&q=images:planking+meme).  Cause that'll never get old.  :)