# What is the word for lying on your stomach facing downwards, the opposite of 'supine'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Today, l learned a new word '*supine*'. It has multiple meanings, but I am asking about the opposite of the following meaning:

> Lying on the back facing upwards.

In other words, what is the suitable word to describe the following:

> Lying on the stomach facing downwards

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [An expression for "Lying on your stomach, kicking your legs and feet up in the air"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336557/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for the word **prone** (which matches the register of "supine"), as defined by [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prone):

> having the front or ventral surface of a body facing downward : lying with the chest and stomach positioned downward
>
> - a patient placed in a prone position
> - The victim was lying prone in the street.

However, the term that came most naturally to me for this was lying **face down**, which must be more common in actual usage.

Comment: +1, but face down and prone aren't the same thing. You can shoot a rifle prone, but not face down.

Answer (score 1):

[Prostrate from MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prostrate): "stretched out with face on the ground in adoration or submission."

(That’s prostrate with an “r,” not prostate.)